# Duplicate e-mail subject from ZF2 Sendmail

Tags: php, zend-framework2, sendmail

I'm working on a form on a Zend Framework 2 website, which sends an e-mail using `Mail\Transport\Sendmail()`.

I don't know if it's a server (I'm working in local, Win10 and XAMPP) or framework problem, but the e-mails I receive have duplicate subject.

My code is quite long but very simple at its core, and I use `setSubject($subject)` to add the subject to the e-mail. If `$subject = "TEST"`, the e-mail I will receive will have the subject "TEST, TEST".

What is wrong and how could I fix this?

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
    $mail = new Mail\Message();
    $mail->setFrom("my@email.com", "Me");
    $mail->addTo($senderEmail, $senderName);
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $mail->setBody($body);
    $transport->send($mail);
}
```

All works fine, but on the received e-mail subject will be duplicated, with a comma in the middle: "$subject, $subject".

Comment: As said, the code is quite simple, so I assume it is a configuration issue from either the framework or my local server. I added a sample code above.

Comment: That's better, but does it trigger the bug?

Comment: Try running `var_dump($subject);` before that code. And see what it has.

Comment: Yes, tried already, even if I use setSubject('TEST') without using variables, I still get 'TEST, TEST' on my e-mail's subject... It's definitely some configuration problem, don't know if it's in the PHP's Sendmail or within Zend Framework 2. :/

Comment: Try checking http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-177 and https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6714 (based on the content there, you are using a Windows server or an ancient version of it, with this bug)

Comment: But I'm using Windows 10 and XAMPP 5.6.15, not Windows server... I'm using Zend Framework 2.3.3, maybe I could try updating it to the latest? Would I have other troubles or need to refactor code if I do that?

Comment: No way, I updated the framework as well and still get the same bug. o_O

Comment: I just had the chance to try my code on a remote Linux host, the bug doesn't show there. I guess it's either some setting on my local host, or some framework bug with Windows/Apache. I don't really need it to work properly in local as long as it's ok on remote, but it would be nice to find a fix for it anyway.

Comment: If you read the links carefully, you will see that this is a Windows-only issue. And both have a fix for it, which requires touching the source code.

Comment: I see, but it should be supposed to be fixed in the framework's updates, shouldn't it? I'm not supposed to go edit the source code from the framework.. By the way, thanks for your help and never mind, hopefully they'll include the fix in next releases!

Comment: It should, but if you see, both links are reporting exactly that: that it was fixed on *NIX but not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I changed the transport agent to Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp instead of using sendmail.

```
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
...
$transport = new SmtpTransport();
```